# When to capitalize common nouns?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

I am having a big problem with capitalization of common nouns. I am reviewing for the IELTS exam and I'm hoping to get impressive results for better employment opportunities.
So here's where I'm having trouble with. Should I or should I not capitalize the word/s in bold fonts?

1. I work as a **receptionist**.
2. The **receptionist** at the hotel is very pretty.
3. There is an opening for **receptionist** at the hotel.
4. You can find many books at the **library**.
5. I worked as **veterinary assistant** for two years in the clinic.

   6. There is a position for **office assistant** at the English Language Center.

Hopefully I can get my mind cleared with this. I will wait for any responses and would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalizing-proper-nouns.html

Comment: Wrong stack - you want [Stack English Language](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @strickt01 Thanks. I thought I posted it in that stack. I don't know how to delete this question though. Any idea how? I'm using the mobile app version.

Comment: @chest_nut, you need to speak to the moderators. I have flagged your post as in the wrong stack but have not had a response. While there is no such reply I thought I'd answer your question and hopefully garner some points!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. It would be better off at, say, https://english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Job titles such as "receptionist", "veterinary assistant" or "office assistant" are not capitalised unless they precede a person's name and thus form part of the proper noun phrase. e.g. Marketing Assistant Jenny Chan is correct but after the name it would be Jenny Chan, marketing assistant for ABC Group.

See [here](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/avoid-capital-offenses-when-using-job-titles/)